# Torus removed two points is homotopy equivalent to wedge sum of three circles

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is an easy way to see that torus with two points removed is homotopy equivalent to wedge of three circles?

I am trying to see it by viewing the torus as a square with two sides identified, but the intuition isn't clear to me, unlike the case with one point removed.

[image]

I am trying to see it as each triangle being retracted to its boundary, but I have no idea how that results in wedge of three circles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually see the three circles in this picture! Look at the three edges incident to the bottom-left corner in your picture. These all become circles after we do the identifications, and they meet at a single point (all four vertices of the rectangle become the same point after identifications). And, after identifications, these three edges are the entire space!

Comment: this is a stupid question, but why only two circles if we have one point punctured, instead of three?

Comment: Where would the three circles come from? If you draw the same diagonal line, only one of the triangles will have a hole in it. This triangle will deformation retract onto its boundary, but the other one will not.

Comment: @diradeltafunk oh yeah, I see your point. I just have terrible intuititon for these lol.